# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity

Tags: android, database, sqlite, create-table

I am getting this error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jitendra.ori/com.example.jitendra.ori.CatalogActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "add": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE add (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, add1 TEXT NOT NULL, add2 TEXT NOT NULL, add3 TEXT NOT NULL, city TEXT, pin INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);
```

My Database create command:

```
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String SQL_CREATE_PETS_TABLE =  "CREATE TABLE " + AddEntry.TABLE_NAME + " ("
            + AddEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + AddEntry.COLUMN_ADD1 + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + AddEntry.COLUMN_ADD2 + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + AddEntry.COLUMN_ADD3 + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + AddEntry.COLUMN_CITY + " TEXT, "
            + AddEntry.COLUMN_PIN + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);";

    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_PETS_TABLE);
}
```

Database contract :

```
    public final static String TABLE_NAME = "add";
    public final static String _ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public final static String COLUMN_ADD1 ="add1";
    public final static String COLUMN_ADD2 = "add2";
    public final static String COLUMN_ADD3 = "add3";
    public final static String COLUMN_CITY = "city";
    public final static String COLUMN_PIN= "pin";
```

Please tell what is wrong in this create table command

Comment: you can not use add as table name. change it and try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add` is a [sqlite keyword](https://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) and cannot be used as identifier such as table name without quoting. Better rename the table.

Comment: This answer is not completely correct. Only **reserved keywords** can not be used without quoting them. Nonreserved keywords are permitted as identifiers without quoting like `begin` and `end` as shown in the example(The example is from MySql documentation) in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

> AddEntry.TABLE_NAME .You should Remove AddEntry . It must be Keyword

Rectify your **Query** .

```
String SQL_CREATE_PETS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
            + AddEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ," 
            + AddEntry.COLUMN_ADD1 + " TEXT NOT NULL ,"
            + AddEntry.COLUMN_ADD2 + " TEXT NOT NULL ," 
            + AddEntry.COLUMN_ADD3 + " TEXT NOT NULL ,"
            + AddEntry.COLUMN_CITY + " TEXT ," 
            + AddEntry.COLUMN_PIN + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0" + ")";
```

**Clean -Rebuild and Run** .

Answer (score 0):

Change table name "add" is a keyword in SQLITE

Answer (score 0):

*Keywords* are words that have significance in SQL. Certain keywords, such as `SELECT`, `DELETE`, or `BIGINT`, are *reserved* and require special treatment for use as identifiers such as table and column names. This may also be true for the names of built-in functions.

*Nonreserved keywords* are permitted as identifiers without quoting. Reserved words are permitted as identifiers if you quote them.

> mysql> CREATE TABLE interval (begin INT, end INT);
>
> ERROR 1064 (42000):
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax ... near 'interval (begin INT,
>   end INT)'

BEGIN and END are keywords but not reserved, so their use as identifiers does not require quoting. INTERVAL is a reserved keyword and must be quoted to be used as an identifier:

> mysql> CREATE TABLE 'interval' (begin INT, end INT);
>
> Query OK, 0 rows
>   affected (0.01 sec)

`ADD` is a reserved keyword so you can not use **add** as a table name.
Change the name or quote it.

For additional information and list of other *Keywords* check this link out. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html